# Insert/replace variables from one list into another list

Tags: python, random, replace

```
list_x = ["a", "y", "l", "d", "e", "q", "g", "o", "i"]
list_y = ["e", "p", "z"]
```

I am trying to replace random items from `list_x` with the items from `list_y` without adding any duplicates. I've looked into `random.replace()` and `random.choice()` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is an example of the output I am trying to get:

```
new_list_x = ["p", "y", "l", "d", "e", "z", "g", "o", "i"]
```

The goal is to insert/replace any letters from `list_y` that are missing in `list_x` without exceeding the original number of letters in `list_x`. If one of the letters from `list_y` is already in `list_x` then skip it. All of `list_y` must be included in `list_x`.

Comment: Is the order of elements in the returned list important? Does the original order of elements in `list_x` need to be preserved?

Comment: @GZ0 My method below keeps the order! I think it's easier that way.

Comment: If the order is unimportant the implementation can be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import random
list_x = ["a", "y", "l", "d", "e", "q", "g", "o", "i"]
list_y = ["e", "p", "z"]

# Create your list
new_list_x = list_x.copy()
for let in list_y:
    # Only add letters not already present (no duplicates)
    if let not in new_list_x:
        # This is needed to find a random letter to replace
        found = False
        while not found:
            num = random.choice(range(len(new_list_x)))
            # Only change letters that are not necessary 
            if new_list_x[num] not in list_y:
                found = True
                new_list_x[num] = let

print(new_list_x)
```

Output:

```
['z', 'y', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'q', 'g', 'o', 'p']
```

Comment: i put your code in a loop with some assertion to check if the requirements are "always" met. maybe i did something wrong but assertions are raised. https://pastebin.com/VEB15uiA

Comment: @Paolo yeah the issue was just that `list_x` already had duplicates in it. As long as it doesn't, this will work. Try again with the new `list_x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list_x = list_x[:] . # makes a copy of list_x
max_index = len(new_list_x) - 1)
for letter in list_y:
    if letter not in list_x:
        new_list_x[random.randint(0, max_index] = letter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list_y:
    if item in list_x:
        pass
    else:
        idx = random.sample(range(len(list_x)),1)[0]
        list_x[idx] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

list_x = ["a", "y", "l", "d", "e", "l", "g", "o", "i"]
list_y = ["e", "p", "z"]
for letter in list_y:
    if letter not in list_x:
        to_be_replaced = random.choice(list_x)
        index_to_be_replaced = list_x.index(to_be_replaced)
        list_x[index_to_be_replaced] = letter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

list_x = ["a", "y", "l", "d", "e", "l", "g", "o", "i"]
list_y = ["e", "p", "z"]

for item in list_y:
    if item in list_x:
        pass
    else:
        list_x[random.randint(0, len(list_x)-1)] = item
print(list_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#removes duplicates 
nondups = set(list_y) - set(list_x)

#gets random numbers 
inds = random.sample(range(len(x)),len(nondups))

for ind, nds in zip(inds, nondups):
    list_x[ind] = nds
```